# Using wildcards to exclude files with a certain suffix

Tags: linux, bash, wildcard

I am experimenting with wildcards in bash and tried to list all the files that start with "xyz" but does not end with ".TXT" but getting incorrect results.

Here is the command that I tried:

```
$ ls -l xyz*[!\.TXT]
```

It is not listing the files with names "xyz" and "xyzTXT" that I have in my directory. However, it lists "xyz1", "xyz123".

It seems like adding `[!\.TXT]` after "xyz*" made the shell look for something that start with "xyz" and has at least one character after it.

Any ideas why it is happening and how to correct this command? I know it can be achieved using other commands but I am especially interested in knowing why it is failing and if it can done just using wildcards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is doable with only wildcards.

Your command isn't working because it means:

Match everything that has `xyz` followed by whatever you want and it must not end with sequent character: `\`, `.`,`T` and `X`. The second `T` doesn't count as far as what you have inside `[]` is read as a family of character and not as a string as you thought.

You don't either need to 'escape' `.` as long as it has no special meaning inside a wildcard.

At least, this is my knowledge of wildcards.

Comment: @RameshSamane, Do some tests, for example, with file called `xyzwhateverTXTyouwant`, `xyzwhateveryouwant.` and `xyzwhateveryouwantX`. Your method will work for the first one but will fail the other two.

Answer (score 7):

These commands will do what you want

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -l xyz!(*.TXT)
shopt -u extglob
```

The reason why your command doesn't work is beacause xyz*[!\.TXT] which is equivalent to  xyz*[!\.TX] means xyz followed by any sequence of character (*) and finally a character in set {!,\,.,T,X} so matches 'xyzwhateveryouwant!' 'xyzwhateveryouwant\' 'xyzwhateveryouwant.' 'xyzwhateveryouwantT' 'xyzwhateveryouwantX'

EDIT: where whateveryouwant does not contain any of !\.TX

Comment: Yes, this works and many thanks for this solution, but any idea why the command that I tried didn't work for the files "xyz" and "xyzTXT"?

Comment: your command matches all files that start with xyz and end with any character within !\.TX

Comment: I created two files with the commands: touch xyz! and touch xyz. The first one that ends with ! gets listed but not the second one that ends with . (dot), I think ! is for negation but why it prints file xyz! is still a mystery.

Comment: Ahh, OK I got it. As per Zagorax's comment above file xyz! should be listed as it does not end with any of the characters \, ., X, T